# Different browsers HTML aligning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, browser, alignment

I have the front page of my Search engine website designed I was using it in Chrome during the construction of the site.

I have  just tested the site in Firefox and IE and the radio boxes and search box / button are aligned left which is not how I wish them to be displayed how do I fix this ?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<meta name="view-part" content="width=device-width, inital-scale =1.0">
<title> Clear Shot Results </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
</head>

  <body>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">


    <a href="#" class="brand">Clear Shot Results </a>
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav pull-right">
        <li  >  <a href='evaluation_form.php'>Survey</a></li>
        <li>  <a href='about.html'>About Us</a></li>
         <li     calss ="active">  <a href='#'>Home</a></li>
</div>
</div>
</div>
              </br>
            </br>
           </br>
   <form method="GET" action="" align="center">
   <div style="text-align: center;"><img border="0" src="sight.jpg" alt="Sniper" width="150" height="150"></div>



           </br>
           Aggregated 
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="AGG"checked  >&nbsp
            Non-aggregated
             <input type="radio" name="choice" value="NonAGG" >&nbsp
             Blekko 
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Blekko" >&nbsp
              Bing                     
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Bing">&nbsp
            Google
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Google"><br />

            </br>
            </br>
            <input name="query" type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" value="<?php

if(isset($_GET["query"]))
   echo $_GET["query"];

?>" /><br />

            <input  class="btn btn-primary btn-large"  type="submit" value="Search" />
            </form>
            <form method="GET" action="" align="center">
            </br>
            </br>
```

Comment: Can you put something up on JsFiddle?

Comment: Off topic: if this is a copy+paste from your site, it looks like `calss ="active"` is a typo bug. Also, `value="AGG"checked` is missing a space, so may not work correctly.

Comment: Also, your HTML needs cleaned up. `align` and 'border' HTML attributes are deprecated in HTML5, your home link has `class` misspelled, and there's a ton of inconsistent white space. The white space thing isn't a technological issue, but it does hinder readability, making various other mistakes harder to catch.

Comment: Sorry not sure what JsFiddle is ... thanks for the typo man!

Comment: you might want to consider having fewer inline styles and attributes, and using a separate stylesheet instead. `align="center"` and `border="0"` are really old-school ways of doing things.

Comment: Hi Shauna - very limited experience with front end can you suggest what would be better than using align ? "a ton of inconsistent white space" what do you mean exactly by this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `text-align:center` CSS property to your form.

[View the JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4D2fQ/)

```
form
{
    text-align:center;  
}
```

OR (*Bad practice.. Use CSS instead of inline styles*)

*Change:*

```
<form method="GET" action="" align="center">
```

*To:*

```
<form method="GET" action="" style="text-align:center;">
```

This works as expected on Firefox, Safari & Chrome.

**[View the working JSFiddle (Click here)](http://jsfiddle.net/4D2fQ/)**